# How can a select elements on a webpage in IE9 when the elements were created with javascript, and not part of the original DOM?

Tags: internet-explorer, webkit, internet-explorer-9, web-inspector

Webkit has the ability to inspect element of the *current* state of the DOM, not the *original* state like IE does.

So, how do I inspect element in IE9 such that I can view / edit the `current` state of the DOM?

currently, when I click the click to select element button in the developer toolbar on an element that was not in the DOM when the page loaded, the developer toolbar just doesn't do anything. =\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the Refresh button in the DOM inspector and try again.

Comment: why is this not automatic? o.o

Answer (score -1):

Does not work.  Switch to Firefox.  IE9 developer tool is junk.  For such an easy thing to test, MS failed miserably on this one.  Spending money on testing their software doesn't make MS money.  Why do it?

Comment: Obviously, since I'm developing on the web, my default is Chrome. I'm not developing in IE by choice...